# Java code skipping the first if condition and is skipping over the others

Tags: java

I am writing a simple program that produces a certain out put when age is less than 13, between 13 and 18 and over 18. My code does not read past the first if statement and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Person {
public  int age;    

public Person(int initialAge) {
    // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
    if (initialAge>-1){
        age=initialAge;
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0. ");
        age=0;
}

public void amIOld() {
    // Write code determining if this person's age is old and print the correct statement:
    if(age<13)
     System.out.println("You are young.");   


    else if(age>=13&&age<18)
        System.out.println("You are a teenager."); 

   else 
    System.out.println("You are old.");


}

public void yearPasses() {
    // Increment this person's age.
    age++;
}
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int T = sc.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
                int age = sc.nextInt();
                Person p = new Person(age);
                p.amIOld();
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    p.yearPasses();
                }
                p.amIOld();
                System.out.println();
            }
           sc.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't read past the first if statement"?  When you step through this in a debugger, what specifically happens that you aren't expecting?  What are the runtime values of the variables when that happens?

Comment: If statements *aren't* simply skipped. If the body of the statement isn't run, it means the condition was falsely. Debug to find out why.

Comment: It keeps printing out "you are young" no matter what age I enter. I am expecting it to print out you are a teenager and you are old when I enter numbers greater than 13 or 18

Comment: @RaghuVarmaManthena: Then this is a good opportunity to use a debugger.  When the error happens, what is the value of `age`?  What value was sent to the constructor?  Stepping through the constructor, which lines of code are executed and what do they do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the constructor, regardless to what's the age, you're setting `age` to `0`. It' not inside the `else` statement. Wrap it with brackets.

Comment: **Always** use brackets even if you think they aren't necessary. That simple habit will save you from unnecessary headaches like this.

Comment: @RaghuVarmaManthena Well, it was SHG's finding, not mine. I *cannot* emphasize that point enough though. *Never* skip brackets. Sacrificing 2 keystrokes for potentially hours of debugging is ridiculous.

Comment: @RaghuVarmaManthena also I suppose passing the parameters to the method and `public void amIOld(int age)` and `public void yearPasses(int age)`. remember to modify the main() according to that.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu: Why would one need to pass a `Person`'s *own values* to it?

Comment: if he is not passing and suppose to use class variable then it may be like `this.age`. thinking in oop way.